# running hive on hue is producing error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hue

i am trying to run ACID on hive on HUE trying to make it work but i keep on getting this error. please helpme where i maybe missing something.

Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 3
2016-02-11 17:36:49,715 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-02-11 17:36:55,971 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.65 sec
2016-02-11 17:37:06,541 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 3.64 sec
2016-02-11 17:37:07,604 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 5.84 sec
2016-02-11 17:37:23,451 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 5.84 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 5 seconds 840 msec
Ended Job = job_1455179102527_0007 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1455179102527_0007_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1455179102527_0007

### Task with the most failures(4):

Task ID:
  task_1455179102527_0007_r_000000

URL:

### http://0.0.0.0:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1455179102527_0007&tipid=task_1455179102527_0007_r_000000

Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":null},"value":null}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":null},"value":null}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:244)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableIntObjectInspector.get(WritableIntObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:235)
    ... 7 more

i clearly see that the error is

Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":null},"value":null}

however im not sure where im missing something.